# Make MainActivity look like changing a to a new window

Tags: android, xml

I have a calendar application and when i swipe left or right i move +/- 1 day i can load the data in to the fields but i want to make the effect like it's sliding on a new page ( like a book page is turned or something like..). I tried with a new intention pointing on the same MainActivity.class but it didn't change anything.

```
if(getIntent()!=null)
    {

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int rowId= extras !=null? extras.getInt(DBAdapter.KEY_pk_ymd):-1;
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(rowId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(rowId<1)
        {
            fillData(Integer.parseInt(keyDen));
        }
        else
        {
            keyDen=String.valueOf(rowId);
            fillData(rowId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This animation sounds VERY confusing what you're trying to imply.. I recommend you do not do this. Unless you're experimenting...

Answer (score 2):

You could try  [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager)

Comes with a lot of options and a demo app